# HubSection default width in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm porting a Wp81 app to UWP, and it seems that the Hub layout strategy changed and it's no longer adapting HubSections width to stretch it (almost) to the width of the screen. How can I achieve that in UWP without setting absolute width on HubSections?

Details about my use case:
In my HubSection, I have an Image, that instead of being shrunk to screen width (almost - so that the next section is visible) it stretches to its native width. The same happens with TextBlock. It seems that in UWP HubSection doesn't have Width or MaxWith set according to screen width.

Comment: Have you tried to check/modify the style of your control?

Comment: @Romasz Yes, and there's no explicit width settings in the Hub style or in the HubSection style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a hub is to allow the user to discover stuff. So the section is not stretched to full screen by default. For you case, you'd better try with Pivot control.
[Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24035.pivot-and-hub-controls-design-guidelines.aspx) is a design guideline for Pivot and Hub.

Besides, if you still want to use Hub and want the style to adapt to different screen size, below is a simple solution by VisualStateManager:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Phone" >
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="HeroImg.Width" Value="100" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Tablet" >
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="HeroImg.Width" Value="800" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Hub Header="News" >
        <HubSection  Header="Hero"  x:Name ="HeroImg" >
            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush   ImageSource="Assets/circle_hero.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </HubSection.Background>
        </HubSection>

    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

Comment: My use case fits the Hub design guidelines. At least let's assume it does so. I added detailed information to the question about what I want to achieve.

Comment: HubSection has "Width", "MinWidth" "MaxWidth" properties. You can check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true

Comment: If you want to adapt to screen size, you can use VisualStateGroups. You can refer to scenario2 in this sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML-Hub-control-sample-5d116fa9

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but it's for Windows 8.1, not Phone and in that scenario hero image (and HubSection) adapts to screen height, not width.

Comment: I've edited my first reply with a detailed sample. Please let me know if anything unclear. I have tested in my UWP app.

Comment: I didn't want to use AdaptiveTrigger since it's actually setting size explicitly, but for this scenario it seems to be the easiest and most flexible solution. I guess that in order to achieve exactly what I wanted I would need to write a Behavior for HubSection that would set its width according to screen width.